# Rollback of down vote added reputation points that the user didnot have

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Today I voted down a question [Project specific help [closed]](https://superuser.com/questions/254695/project-specific-help-closed) as I wanted it to be closed .When it was closed I tried to roll back my down vote and it worked.Now this user started at a Reputation score of 1 so when i voted his query down naturally it was still at one , but on rolling back he got back the 2 point that were never taken from him .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design.

The original down-vote would take the users reputation to -1, but this is always displayed as 1.

The removal of the vote will restore the 2 points of rep taking the score up to 3.

Comment: so this is intentional ? I guess a score of 1 or 3  doesn't really make any difference but i though it was actually a bug :)

Comment: @Shark - actually "by design" might not be strictly accurate ;) It's certainly an artefact of the way the system works, but may have only been discovered after the fact at which point it was decided not to fix it. Check on MSO for more questions on this.

Comment: @shark this is because users can never go below 1 rep. It's such a small discrepancy that we don't feel it's worth "fixing", and has been that way since forever.

Comment: @jeff thats what i realized too, but i thought it was by an oversight :)